# Constructors in class with only pure virtual functions causes errors in derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have an abstract class, `IPrinter` that contains only pure virtual functions.

```
using namespace std;
class IPrinter
{
public:
    virtual void Print() =0;
    virtual void Print(string) = 0;
    virtual void SetStreamData(string) =0;
private:
    IStreamBehavior* streamBehavior;
    string _name;
};
```

And a class that implements it

```
class HtmlPrinter :
    public IPrinter
{
public:
    HtmlPrinter();
    HtmlPrinter(IPrinter*);
    ~HtmlPrinter();
    virtual void Print();
    virtual void Print(string);
    vector<string> GetPrintList();
    virtual void SetStreamData(string);
private:
    IPrinter* printer;
    string streamData;
    void Paragraph();
};
```

cpp

```
HtmlPrinter::HtmlPrinter()
{
}
//error on this line
HtmlPrinter::HtmlPrinter(IPrinter* printer) :printer(printer){}

void HtmlPrinter::Print()
{
    this->printer->Print();
}
void HtmlPrinter::Print(string s)
{

}
vector<string> HtmlPrinter::GetPrintList()
{
    vector<string> myStrings;
    return myStrings;
}
void HtmlPrinter::SetStreamData(string streamData)
{
    this->streamData = streamData;
}
HtmlPrinter::~HtmlPrinter()
{
}
void HtmlPrinter::Paragraph()
{
    string old = streamData;
    streamData += "<p>" + old += "</p>";
}
```

When I add a constructor or destructor to `IPrinter` I get an error in the constructor of `HtmlPrinter` that takes `IPrinter*`.  Why can't I add a constructor/destructor to `IPrinter`?

Error Message:

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall 

    IPrinter::IPrinter(void)" (??0IPrinter@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall HtmlPrinter::HtmlPrinter(class IPrinter *)" (??0HtmlPrinter@@QAE@PAVIPrinter@@@Z)    C:\Users\darrin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ShapeStore\ShapeStore\HtmlPrinter.obj ShapeStore
```

Comment: Any reason you don't provide us with the error message? Also don't forget virtual destructor and I suggest you pass those strings by const reference.

Comment: "I get an error" - are we supposed to guess what that is? It's getting a bit late for those kind of games.

Comment: It looks like you declared the constructor, but didn't implement it. Or maybe you didn't include the file that implements it in the build. (Also, you should give the base class a virtual destructor.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour that's correct, I should have mentioned that I did not implement `IPrinter` at all.  I thought that might be the problem, but why does it not compile?  Why does IPrinter need a constructor?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: It doesn't link because you declared the constructor but didn't implement it. I don't know why (or if) it needs one; it's you that declared it. If you want it to do something (initialising the member variables, perhaps), then implement it. If you don't, then don't declare it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I can't see an `IPrinter` constructor declared in the code.

Comment: @NeilKirk: You mean you can't see the constructor? No, it's not in the posted code, which compiles. Then the question says "When I add a constructor or destructor to `IPrinter` I get an error", the error indicating that the constructor was only declared.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Ah sorry I missed that bit.

Comment: @MikeSeymour you can declare functions in a header file and not implement them without a compiler error.  Why not for a constructor?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie, it woudl be nice if you could show the code that actually produces the error.  Makes it easier to diagnose.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: You have to implement every function that's used. The constructor is used (implicitly) when the derived class's constructor calls it to initialise its base object.

Comment: @MikeSeymour that's the piece that I was missing.  Thanks +1

Comment: There's another big flaw in your code: The members you declared in your `IPrinter` baseclass are not accessible to anyone, just remove them. It's also interesting that `HTMLPrinter` both is an `IPrinter` and uses an `IPrinter`, is that supposed to be an application of the Decorator Pattern?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yes, it was.  This is really my first sizable project where I'm consciously trying to implement the various design patterns where they're needed.

Answer (score 0):

i dont find any error in ur code.check this once

```js
<script src="http://ideone.com/e.js/1HWcfn" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

http://ideone.com/1HWcfn